# C++ referencing an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm new to using C++ for complicated programming. I've been sifting through some leftover, uncommented, academic code handed down through my department, and I've stumbled across something I have no real idea how to google for. I don't understand the syntax in referencing an array of structs.

Here is a trimmed version of what I'm struggling with:

```
typedef struct
{
    double x0,y0;
    double r;
} circle;

double foo()
{
    int N = 3;
    double mtt;
    circle circles[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        mtt += mtt_call_func((circles+i), N);
    }

    return mtt;
}
```

What does `(circles+i)` mean in this case?

EDIT: the function should have `(circles + i)`, not `(circle + i)`.

Comment: Does it compile? It should be `circles + i`

Comment: It depends on the size of the struct. You need to call `sizeof(circle)` so you can find out exactly how big your struct is with padding, because then when you declare an array of structs, the contiguous memory is aligned exactly in the order that the members of your struct are declared.

Comment: `circle` is a type. Presumably your code should say `(circles + i)`.

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ and not C?

Comment: @NeilKirk Should compile in both cases, so technically it is both.

Comment: @khajvah variable sized array

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, you right!

Comment: @DragosRizescu, you're correct, I went ahead and made an edit. Thanks.

Comment: @NeilKirk the file has a .cpp ending, so I just went with C++.

Comment: I think there is a way to compile a code with variable sized arrays with some additional options to g++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`circles+i` is equivalent to `&circles[i]`. That's how pointer arithmetic works in C++.

Why is there a pointer? Well, when you give the name of an array, in a context other than `&circles` or `sizeof circles`, a temporary pointer is created that points to the first member of the array; that's what your code works with.  Arrays are second-class citizens in C++; they don't behave like objects.

(I'm assuming your `circle+i` was a typo for `circles+i` as the others suggested)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're correct (I made an edit on the original question). You explained this very concisely, I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer for the extra background information.

Answer (score 2):

`circle+i` means "take a pointer circle and move it i times by the size of the object pointed to by it". Pointer is involved because the name of the array is a pointer to it's first element.

Apart from this you should initialize an integer counter variable that is used in loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           ^^^^
{
    mtt += mtt_call_func( ( circles + i), N);
                                  ^ // typo
}
```

Comment: should not* i think you meant

Comment: Misread, I thought you were telling him not to declare the variable inside the loop.

Comment: You should explain why a pointer is involved, because `circles` is an _array_, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for this, that makes sense. You're correct, it was a transcription error; the original file does have the integer counter initialized in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In C, as in C++, it is legal to treat an array as a pointer. So `circles+i` adds `i` times the size of `circle` to the address of `circles`.

It might be clearer to write `&circles[i]`; in this form, it is more obvious that the expression produces a pointer to the ith struct in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Each vector you declare in stack it's actually a pointer to the first index, 0, of the vector. Using i you move from index to index. As result, `(circles+i)` it's the equivalent of `&circles[i]`.

`&` means the address of the variable. As in your function call, you send a pointer which stores an address of a variable, therefore `&` is required in front of `circles[i]` if you were to change to that, as you need the address of the i index of the vector circles to run your function.

For more about pointers, vectors and structures check this out: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

It should cover you through ground basics.